# I have an error in my code when i import data from fierbase i cant import the docs in the code

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9oYH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9oYH.png)

body: FutureBuilder(
future: usersref.get() ,
builder:(context, snapshot){

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
return ListView.builder(
itemCount:snapshot.data!.docs.length,
itemBuilder: (context,i){
return Text("");
});

}

if(snapshot.hasError){
}
else{
return Text("LOADING . . . .")
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please attach a screenshot or the code of the get() method you're using to fetch the users,
also try:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream :usersref.get(),
    builder : (context, snapshot){
    return Column(
    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
      (element){
          return Text(element.data()['username']);
           } 
         ),   
      ),
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).